# How to linearize this equation in two different variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, nonlinear

How to linearize this equation in two different variables `p[t]` and `q[t,y]`:

```
ein11= -((1/(p[t] + q[t, y])^3)*(4*p[t]*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]^2 +   4*q[t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]^2 - 17*a[t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]*
          Derivative[0, 1][q][t, y] + 18*a[t, y]*p[t]*Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y] + 
             18*a[t, y]*q[t, y]*  Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y] + (p[t] + q[t, y])^2*
               (Derivative[2][p][t] + (Derivative[1, 0][a][t, 
                 y]*(Derivative[1][p][t] + Derivative[1, 0][q][t, y]))/
              a[t, y] + Derivative[2, 0][q][t, y])[
           Derivative[1][p][t] + Derivative[1, 0][q][t, y], t]))
```

I tried:

```
 Normal[Series[ ein11 /. {q -> Function[{t, y}, k*q[t, y]], p -> Function[{t}, ep*p[t]]}, {k, 0, 1}, {ep, 0, 1}]]
```

But this linearize only one parameter `q[t,y]` and let unlinearized terms of order `p[t]^3`

```
   Out[30]= -((2*(2*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]^2 + 
                9*a[t, y]*Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y]))/(ep^2*p[t]^2)) + 
           (k*(8*q[t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]^2 + 
              17*a[t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][q][t, y] + 
                   36*a[t, y]*q[t, y]*Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y]))/(ep^3*
            p[t]^3) + (-(1/(ep*p[t])) + (k*q[t, y])/(ep^2*p[t]^2))*
             (ep*Derivative[2][p][
               t] + (Derivative[1, 0][a][t, 
                 y]*(ep*Derivative[1][p][t] + k*Derivative[1, 0][q][t, y]))/
              a[t, y] + 
                  k*Derivative[2, 0][q][t, y])[
           ep*Derivative[1][p][t] + k*Derivative[1, 0][q][t, y], t]
```

**Edit**

I try to linearize this term in `q[t]` and `p[t,y]`

```
t00= (covd[Derivative[1][q][t] + Derivative[1, 0][p][t, y], t] + 
      2*(1 + 
      2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])*(Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y]*
             (4*(p[t, y] + q[t])*Derivative[0, 1][a][t, y] -  a[t, y]*Derivative[0, 1][p][t, y]) + 
      2*a[t, y]*(p[t, y] + q[t])*
             Derivative[0, 2][a][t, y]))/(2*
   a[t, y]^2*(p[t, y] + q[t])^3*  (1 + 2*\[Alpha][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]))
```

by

`Normal[Series[t00 /. {q -> (eps q[#] &), p -> (eps p[#] &)}, {eps, 0, 1}]]`

But it does not work. `(P[t]+q[t])^3` terms still there.

Comment: In your expression `ein11` there is  an argument bracket `...[Derivative[1][p][t] + Derivative[1, 0][q][t, y], t]` Is this intended or should it be a normal bracket?

Comment: Hi @UlrichNeumann. Thanks for your answer. May you please see the question edit. I try to use the answer's code in another new term, but it has been linearized.

Comment: In your code `covd[]` is undefined!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann. Yeah, it's a variable I will define later.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann. Also I found this replacement can help `{q :> (eps q[##] &), p :> (eps p[##] &)}`. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Normal[Series[ein11 /. {p -> (eps p[#] &), q -> (eps q[#] &)}, {eps, 0, 1}]]/.eps -> 1
```

$-\frac{2 \left(2 a^{(0,1)}(t,y)^2+9 a(t,y) a^{(0,2)}(t,y)\right)}{(p(t)+q(t))^2}$